# Rewriting Bison grammar to fix shift/reduce conflicts

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison

Here are the relevant parts of my Bison grammar rules:

```
statement:
  expression ';' |
  IF expression THEN statement ELSE statement END_IF ';' 
  ;

expression:
  IDENTIFIER |
  IDENTIFIER '('expressions')' |
  LIT_INT |
  LIT_REAL |
  BOOL_OP |
  LOG_NOT expression |
  expression operator expression |
  '('expression')'
  ;

expressions:
  expression |
  expressions ',' expression  
  ;

operator: 
  REL_OP |
  ADD_OP |
  MULT_OP |
  LOG_OR  |
  LOG_AND
  ;
```

When compiling, I get 10 shift/reduce conflicts:

5 conflicts are caused by the **LOG_NOT expression** rule:

```
State 45

   25 expression: LOG_NOT expression .
   26           | expression . operator expression

    REL_OP   shift, and go to state 48
    ADD_OP   shift, and go to state 49
    MULT_OP  shift, and go to state 50
    LOG_OR   shift, and go to state 51
    LOG_AND  shift, and go to state 52

    REL_OP    [reduce using rule 25 (expression)]
    ADD_OP    [reduce using rule 25 (expression)]
    MULT_OP   [reduce using rule 25 (expression)]
    LOG_OR    [reduce using rule 25 (expression)]
    LOG_AND   [reduce using rule 25 (expression)]
    $default  reduce using rule 25 (expression)

    operator  go to state 54
```

5 conflicts are caused by the **expressions operator expression** rule:

```
State 62

   26 expression: expression . operator expression
   26           | expression operator expression .

    REL_OP   shift, and go to state 48
    ADD_OP   shift, and go to state 49
    MULT_OP  shift, and go to state 50
    LOG_OR   shift, and go to state 51
    LOG_AND  shift, and go to state 52

    REL_OP    [reduce using rule 26 (expression)]
    ADD_OP    [reduce using rule 26 (expression)]
    MULT_OP   [reduce using rule 26 (expression)]
    LOG_OR    [reduce using rule 26 (expression)]
    LOG_AND   [reduce using rule 26 (expression)]
    $default  reduce using rule 26 (expression)

    operator  go to state 54
```

I know that the problem has to do with precedence. For instance, if the expression was:

**a + b * c**

Does Bison shift after the a + and hope to find an expression, or does it reduce the a to an expression? I have a feeling that this is due to the Bison 1-token look-ahead limitation, but I can't figure out how to rewrite the rule(s) to resolve the conflicts.

My professor will take points off for shift/reduce conflicts, so I can't use %expect. My professor has also stated that we cannot use %left or %right precedence values.

This is my first post on Stack, so please let me know if I'm posting this all wrong. I've searched existing posts, but this really seems a case-by-case thing. If I use any code from Stack, I will note the source in my submitted project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As written, your grammar is ambiguous. So it must have conflicts.

There is no inherent rule of binding precedences, and apparently you're not allowed to use bison's precedence declarations either. If you were allowed to, you wouldn't be able to use `operator` as a non-terminal, because you need to distinguish between

```
expr1 + expr2 * expr3             expr1 * expr2 + expr3
  |       |       |                 |       |       |
  |       +---+---+                 +---+---+       |
  |           |                         |           |
  |          expr                      expr         |
  |           |                         |           |
  +-----+-----+                         +-----+-----+         
        |                                     |
       expr                                  expr
```

And you cannot distinguish between them if `+` and `*` are replaced with `operator`. The terminals actually have to be visible.

Now, here's a quick clue:

```
expr1 + expr2 + expr3    reduces expr1 + expr2 first
expr1 * expr2 + expr3    reduces expr1 * expr2 first
```

So in `non-terminal-1 + non-terminal-2`, `non-terminal-1` cannot produce `x + y` or `x * y`. But in `non-terminal-1 * non-terminal-2`, `non-terminal-1` can produce `x + y

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking that I could resolve the problem by changing one of the tokens, but I now realize that the whole structure of the expression grammar was causing the conflicts. I think I may have fixed the conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I did some more troubleshooting, and fixed the reduce/conflict errors by rewriting the **expression** and **operator** rules:

```
expression:
  expression LOG_OR term1 |
  term1
  ;

term1:
  term1 LOG_AND term2 |
  term2
  ;

term2:
  term2 REL_OP term3 |
  term3
  ;

term3:
  term3 ADD_OP term4 |
  term4
  ;

term4:
  term4 MULT_OP factor |
  factor
  ;

factor:
  IDENTIFIER |
  IDENTIFIER '('expressions')' |
  LIT_INT |
  LIT_REAL |
  BOOL_OP |
  LOG_NOT factor |
  '('expression')'
  ;

expressions:
  expression |
  expressions ',' expression  
  ;
```

I had to rearrange what was actually an **expression** and what was actually a **factor**. I made a **factor** rule that includes all of the factors (terminals), which has the highest precedence. I then made a **term#** rule for each expression, which also sets them at different precedence levels (term5 has higher precedence than term4, term4 has higher precedence than term3, etc.).

This allowed me to set each operator at a difference precedence without using any of the built-in % precedence functions.

I was able to parse all of my test input files without error. Any thoughts on the design?